# Error installing web3 using pip. Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ipfshttpclient==0.7.0

Tags: python, pip, web3py

I had trouble installing web3 using pip. I run 'pip install web3' and get the below error

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ipfshttpclient==0.7.0 (from web3) (from versions: 0.4.10, 0.4.11, 0.4.12, 0.4.13, 0.4.13.1, 0.4.13.2, 0.6.0, 0.6.0.post1, 0.6.1)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for ipfshttpclient==0.7.0 (from web3)

My python version is 3.7.2. I have tried installing ipfshttpclient but it still returns the same error

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
pip3 install --no-cache-dir web3
```

https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/1052#issuecomment-420244151

Comment: بدون هیچ مشکلی کارکرد و ممنونم